# spark maven package org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm does not exist

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I use Maven to manage my java spark program. In the program I call the FPGrowth algorithm in mllib.fpm.

```
<dependency> <!--Spark denpendency -->
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifacrId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However there is an error :package org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm does not exist. How to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using mllib but you do not have its dependency specified in your pom.xml.

As i can see your spark version is 1.5.1.

Hence try adding this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This would solve your issue. Thanks !

Comment: The version should really be 1.5.1. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You're welcome! As @ShivanshSrivastava mentioned the version should be 1.5.1